# Is there a chart of all possible Chinese syllables using Hanzi?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology

I have been able to find many charts that describe all possible Initial and Final combinations in pinyin, but I'm wondering if there is anything available like that that uses Hanzi only?

I made something like what I'm looking for and pasted it below (you'll have to paste it into a text editor like notepad++ to get it to look like a table...)

I'm wondering if anyone else has made something like this and if so, how it might be different from what I've made here.

Thanks!

```
安 半 盘 满 饭 但 谈 南 兰 干 看 汉 ◎ ◎ ◎ 站 产 山 然 赞 参 散
昂 帮 胖 忙 方 当 堂 囊 朗 港 康 航 ◎ ◎ ◎ 张 场 上 让 脏 藏 桑
鞥 崩 朋 梦 风 等 藤 能 冷 更 坑 恒 ◎ ◎ ◎ 正 城 声 仍 增 曾 僧
物 部 普 木 福 度 图 努 路 古 哭 湖 ◎ ◎ ◎ 猪 除 书 如 足 粗 苏
我 波 破 末 佛 多 脱 诺 罗 果 括 或 ◎ ◎ ◎ 桌 缀 说 弱 坐 错 所
挖 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 挂 跨 话 ◎ ◎ ◎ 爪 欻 刷 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎
外 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 怪 快 坏 ◎ ◎ ◎ 拽 揣 摔 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎
王 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 光 况 黄 ◎ ◎ ◎ 状 创 爽 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎
阿 把 怕 马 发 大 他 那 拉 嘎 卡 哈 ◎ ◎ ◎ 炸 茶 杀 ◎ 杂 擦 撒
爱 白 牌 麦 ◎ 代 太 奶 来 该 开 还 ◎ ◎ ◎ 摘 拆 晒 ◎ 在 菜 赛
恶 ◎ ◎ 么 ◎ 德 特 呢 乐 格 克 和 ◎ ◎ ◎ 者 车 设 热 则 厕 色
恩 本 喷 门 分 扽 ◎ 嫩 ◎ 跟 肯 很 ◎ ◎ ◎ 镇 沉 深 人 怎 岑 森
奥 包 跑 毛 ◎ 道 逃 脑 老 高 靠 好 ◎ ◎ ◎ 照 超 少 扰 早 草 扫
欧 ◎ 剖 某 否 豆 头 獳 楼 狗 口 后 ◎ ◎ ◎ 周 抽 手 肉 走 湊 搜
湾 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 段 团 暖 乱 馆 宽 换 ◎ ◎ ◎ 传 穿 拴 软 钻 窜 算
味 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 对 退 ◎ ◎ 贵 亏 会 ◎ ◎ ◎ 追 垂 水 锐 最 崔 虽
◎ 北 培 美 非 得 忒 内 类 给 ◎ 黑 ◎ ◎ ◎ 这 ◎ 谁 ◎ 贼 ◎ ◎
◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 顿 屯 黁 论 滚 困 婚 ◎ ◎ ◎ 准 春 顺 润 遵 村 隼
◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 东 通 农 龙 公 空 红 ◎ ◎ ◎ 中 虫 ◎ 容 总 从 送 

鱼 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 女 绿 ◎ ◎ ◎ 据 去 许 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎
月 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 虐 略 ◎ ◎ ◎ 决 却 血 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎
云 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 军 群 巡 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎
原 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 卷 泉 宣 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎
义 必 皮 米 ◎ 地 体 你 里 ◎ ◎ ◎ 机 气 喜 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 
也 别 撇 灭 ◎ 蝶 铁 捏 列 ◎ ◎ ◎ 节 且 写 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎
要 表 票 苗 ◎ 掉 条 鸟 料 ◎ ◎ ◎ 叫 桥 小 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 
眼 边 片 面 ◎ 点 天 年 连 ◎ ◎ ◎ 见 前 现 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 
英 并 平 明 ◎ 定 听 宁 领 ◎ ◎ ◎ 京 请 星 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 
因 滨 品 民 ◎ ◎ ◎ 您 林 ◎ ◎ ◎ 金 亲 新 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 
压 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 俩 ◎ ◎ ◎ 家 恰 下 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎
羊 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 娘 两 ◎ ◎ ◎ 将 强 想 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 
有 ◎ ◎ 谬 ◎   丢 ◎ 牛 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 久 求 休 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎
永 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎   ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 窘 穹 雄 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎

而 ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎   ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎
◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎   ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ ◎ 之 吃 事 日 自 次 思
```

Comment: What's the purpose? Just curious... Anyway, if you consider all 4 tones, you'll have an extremely huge list.

Comment: I'm exploring the relationship between initials and finals (separate from tones) and I think that there are some irregularities in pinyin, which don't show some connections between syllables, like wo and duo, or yan and dian have the same final but they are written differently in pinyin. Also, I was thinking that having a complete "word" to go with each syllable would be more helpful than a list of unmarked pinyin.

Answer (score 3):

我 should be 哦, in the -o group: o, bo, po, mo, fo, lo. It is conflated with the -uo group: wo, duo, tuo, nuo, luo, guo, kuo, huo, zhuo, chuo, shuo, ruo, zuo, cuo, suo.

The -i group is also missing: zhi, chi, shi, ri, zi, ci, si (different from yi, bi, pi etc.). Back to the drawing table. And don't neglect the tones.

Has it been done before? Yes:

> [image]
>   ([source](http://input.foruto.com/cccl/cccl_article025.htm))

and

> [image]
>   ([source](http://appwk.baidu.com/naapi/doc/view?ih=756&rn=1&doc_id=34405355ad02de80d4d8400a&o=jpg_6_0_______&pn=1&iw=1157&ix=0&sign=9bea64db37e000cb352d19100141ad49&type=1&iy=0&aimw=1157&app_ver=2.9.8.2&ua=bd_800_800_IncredibleS_2.9.8.2_2.3.7&bid=1&app_ua=IncredibleS&uid=&cuid=&fr=3&Bdi_bear=WIFI&from=3_10000&bduss=&pid=1&screen=800_800&sys_ver=2.3.7))

and  etc.

Answer (score 3):

I have put together an eleven-page Excel spreadsheet listing all Mandarin syllables. If there is any interest, I'll speed up my proofreading and make it generally available. Comments are welcome.

My table includes:

(1) A representative character for each common syllable (HSK 1~4)

(2) A number [but no character] for rare syllables

(3) A hash mark for non-existent syllables.

(4) Toneless Zhuyin (Bopomofo)

(5) Toneless Hanyu Pinyin

(6) Complete syllables spelled in Gwoyeu Romatzyh tonal spelling

Here is a sample:

[image: Juhin--Pinyin--GR Mandarin Syllables]

I have not finished proofreading it, however, so it is not yet ready for distribution.

Comment: I'm interested in the tone data for sure. Let me know when it's ready!